# Rs485 receiving problem in Pic microcontroller

Tags: pic, rs485

I started to work on Rs485 (Sp3485c) which is interfaced with Pic24fj128ga202 microcotroller IC. This controller has 4 uart's  one is connected to pc through max3232 ic ,gps,gsm and another for rs485.uart1,2,3 have been configured very correctly and i can able to send and receive data through these uarts, but when i send data through the fourth uart data gets transmitted i checked the transmission through tx interrupt . For checking purpose i made one microcontroller as transmitter and another mocricontroller as receiver both the controller are connected through rs485 . The major problem is i dont receive any data in another microcontroller through rs485.

Here is the transmitter code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

//#include "p24FJ128GA202.h"              // Pic24FJ128GA202 header file
#include "C:\Program     Files\Microchip\xc16\v1.24\support\PIC24F\h\p24FJ128GA202.h"
#include "uart.h"
#define PWRKEY    PORTBbits.RB12

// Function Prototypes
void InitProcessor(void);
void InitDelayms(void);
void Timer2Init(void);
void Delayms(uint16_t delay);

void __attribute__ ((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _U4TXInterrupt(void) 
{ 
    uart1tx('O');
    IFS5bits.U4TXIF   = 0;  
} 

int main()
{
    unsigned int i=0;
    InitProcessor();
    Delayms(500);                                               // oscillator to get lock
    uart1str((unsigned char *)"\r\nRs485 Transmitter\r\n");
    while(1)
    {
        uart4tx('T');
        Delayms(3000);
    }
    return 0;
}

void InitProcessor(void)
{
    // Oscillator
    OSCCON = 0x0011;
    CLKDIV = 0x0000; 

//PPS for UART1
RPINR18bits.U1RXR   = 7;   //UART1 receive set to RB7
RPOR4bits.RP8R      = 3;   //UART1 transmit set to RB8

//PPS for UART2
RPINR19bits.U2RXR   = 14;  // uart2 receive set to RB14
RPOR6bits.RP13R     = 5;   //UART2 transmit set to RB13
//PPS for UART4
RPINR27bits.U4RXR   = 4;  // uart4 RX
RPOR3bits.RP6R      = 21;   //UART4 

// Configure Digital pins
ANSA = 0x0003;
ANSB = 0x0000;

//  Assign  IO values for Ports
PORTA = 0x0000;
TRISA = 0x001B;
TRISB = 0x469f;                   // 7 as receive and 8 as transmitter
//PORTB = 0x0000;

// Init UART1
U1MODE = 0x0000;
U1STA = 0x0000;                   //Enable Transmission, Clear all flags
U1BRG = 103;//25;9600
U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;            // And turn the peripheral on
U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;

// Init UART2
U2MODE = 0x0000;
U2STA  = 0x0000;                  //Enable Transmission, Clear all flags
U2BRG  = 103;
U2MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;            // And turn the peripheral on
U2STAbits.UTXEN = 1;

U4MODE = 0x0000;
U4STA  = 0x0000;                  //Enable Transmission, Clear all flags
U4BRG  = 103;
IFS5bits.U4TXIF   = 0;  
IEC5bits.U4TXIE   = 1;
U4MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;            // And turn the peripheral on
U4STAbits.UTXEN = 1;

// Interrupt Bits 
INTCON1 = 0x0000;                                               // Disable  Interrupts
INTCON2 = 0x0000;


InitDelayms();
PWRKEY = 1;
Delayms(1000);
}

void InitDelayms(void)
{
    // T1 - Clk Source: Fosc/2 (Fcyc)
    T1CONbits.TCS = 0;
    // T1 - Pre scale: 1:1 (4MHz / 250nS per tick)
    T1CONbits.TCKPS = 0;
    // PR1 adjusted to account for sw delays intro'd in loop below at 16MHz
    PR1 = 16000;
    // Clear TMR1
    TMR1 = 0;
    // Reset T1IF
    IFS0bits.T1IF = 0;
    // T1 - Turn on
    T1CONbits.TON = 1;
}
void Delayms(uint16_t delay)
{
    // basic kernel is 1mS (32 ticks @ 31.25uS/tick)

    while(delay>0)
    {
        // Clear TMR1
        TMR1 = 0;
        // Reset T1IF
        IFS0bits.T1IF = 0;
        // Wait 1mS
        while(!IFS0bits.T1IF);
        delay--;
    }

}
```

which transmits data for every 3 second.
Receiver Code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include<stdbool.h>

    //#include "p24FJ128GA202.h"              // Pic24FJ128GA202 header file
    #include "C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc16\v1.24\support\PIC24F\h\p24FJ128GA202.h"
    #include "uart.h"
    #define PWRKEY    PORTBbits.RB12

    // Function Prototypes
    void InitProcessor(void);
    void InitDelayms(void);
    void Timer2Init(void);
    void Delayms(uint16_t delay);
    void __attribute__ ((interrupt,no_auto_psv)) _U4RXInterrupt(void)
    {
        uart1tx(uart4rx());
        IFS5bits.U4RXIF   = 0;       
    }

    int main()
    {
        unsigned int i=0;
        InitProcessor();
        Delayms(500);                                               // oscillator to get lock
        uart1str((unsigned char *)"\r\nRs485 with Modbus Protocol\r\n");
        Rs485Re_De=0;    // receiver
        while(1)
        {
            Delayms(1000);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void InitProcessor(void)
    {
        // Oscillator
        OSCCON = 0x0011;
        CLKDIV = 0x0000; 

        //PPS for UART1
        RPINR18bits.U1RXR   = 7;   //UART1 receive set to RB7
        RPOR4bits.RP8R      = 3;   //UART1 transmit set to RB8

        //PPS for UART2
        RPINR19bits.U2RXR   = 14;  // uart2 receive set to RB14
        RPOR6bits.RP13R     = 5;   //UART2 transmit set to RB13
        //PPS for UART4
        RPINR27bits.U4RXR   = 4;  // uart4 RX
        RPOR3bits.RP6R      = 21;   //UART4 

        // Configure Digital pins
        ANSA = 0x0003;
        ANSB = 0x0000;

        //  Assign  IO values for Ports
        PORTA = 0x0000;
        TRISA = 0x001B;
        TRISB = 0x469f;                   // 7 as receive and 8 as transmitter
        //PORTB = 0x0000;

        // Init UART1
        U1MODE = 0x0000;
        U1STA = 0x0000;                   //Enable Transmission, Clear all flags
        U1BRG = 103;//25;9600
        U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;            // And turn the peripheral on
        U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;

        // Init UART2
        U2MODE = 0x0000;
        U2STA  = 0x0000;                  //Enable Transmission, Clear all flags
        U2BRG  = 103;
        U2MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;            // And turn the peripheral on
        U2STAbits.UTXEN = 1;

        U4MODE = 0x0000;
        U4STA  = 0x0000;                  //Enable Transmission, Clear all flags
        U4BRG  = 103;
        IFS5bits.U4RXIF   = 0;            // Clear the Receive Interrupt Flag
        IEC5bits.U4RXIE   = 1;            // Enable Receive Interrupts
        U4MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;            // And turn the peripheral on
        U4STAbits.UTXEN = 1;

        // Interrupt Bits 
        INTCON1 = 0x0000;                                               // Disable  Interrupts
        INTCON2 = 0x0000;


        InitDelayms();
        PWRKEY = 1;
        Delayms(1000);
    }

    void InitDelayms(void)
    {
        // T1 - Clk Source: Fosc/2 (Fcyc)
        T1CONbits.TCS = 0;
        // T1 - Pre scale: 1:1 (4MHz / 250nS per tick)
        T1CONbits.TCKPS = 0;
        // PR1 adjusted to account for sw delays intro'd in loop below at 16MHz
        PR1 = 16000;
        // Clear TMR1
        TMR1 = 0;
        // Reset T1IF
        IFS0bits.T1IF = 0;
        // T1 - Turn on
        T1CONbits.TON = 1;
    }
    void Delayms(uint16_t delay)
    {
        // basic kernel is 1mS (32 ticks @ 31.25uS/tick)

        while(delay>0)
        {
            // Clear TMR1
            TMR1 = 0;
            // Reset T1IF
            IFS0bits.T1IF = 0;
            // Wait 1mS
            while(!IFS0bits.T1IF);
            delay--;
        }

    }
```

i have written a interrupt function for receiver which prints any data on reception , the problem is here where i am not getting any data

Pic to PIC connection diagram
Pic1 A - Pic2 A
Pic1 B - Pic2 B
Pic1 Gnd - Pic2 Gnd  respectively.

Pic2 uart1 to max 3232 to pc for viewing output.
[image: pic controller]

[image: Rs485]

[image: Output connector]

these are the PIC ,RS485,Output diagram respectively.

Comment: I have concerns about some parts of your "Receiver Code", but since you are supplying both transmitter and receiver code, it seems you are not sure where your problem(s) is/are. One simple approach is to use your oscilloscope on the RS-485 bus, to confirm whether the transmitter is sending ASCII "T" every 3 seconds, as implied in your code, and confirm the signal levels and data rate from the oscilloscope trace. If you *do not* see the correct signal on the RS-485 bus - focus your troubleshooting on the transmitter; if you *do* see the correct signal - focus on the receiver.

Comment: `#include "C:\Program     Files\Microchip\xc16\v1.24\support\PIC24F\h\p24FJ128GA202.h"`   Yuck!

Comment: Your description is borderline comprehensible.  Try again in English.

Answer (score 0):

The SN75176 is a 5V device and not 3.3 volts. Try changing the device: -

[image]

Comment: Just in schematic we used sn75176 but in our board we used sp3485c ic , i forget to mention that ..

Comment: Then you are a time waster.

Comment: what do you  mean by time waster? if i am wrong suggest the correction where i did mistake. you don't have any rights to say about me.. Mind it..

Comment: You HAVE SN75176 written in the middle of the RS485 device! That makes you a time waster.

Comment: If you want accurate answers you should provide an accurate question.  Please edit the supplementary details into your question to prevent other people wasting their time.